# Change subtitles style during video

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to change the subtitle style during the video?

I am using the `subtitles` filter (ffmpeg compiled with `--enable-libass`).

What I would like to do, if possible, is to change randomly the style of subtitles added from a SubRip file across the whole video.

Thanks

Comment: You would define multiple styles in the ASS file, and then assign the styles to each line as you want.

Comment: okay so I would need to preprocess the ASS file before passing to ffmpeg. Isn't there a way to do this inside ffmpeg? (I was using *.srt* files and not *ASS* but conversion is not a problem)

Comment: The filter accepts a style option but it can be changed mid-way.

Comment: Okay, that is what I thought. So now I am writing a script to rewrite ass files. Thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear, that should read *can't be changed*

Comment: That sentence wasn't clear hahaha. I guess you mean that once the file has been modified the changes are somewhat permanent? If so it's no problem, what I am basically doing generating plenty of ass files from one and use them.

Comment: That's what you should do, yes.

Comment: Alright thanks. If you want to get an answer just tell me that there is no way to do this in ffmpeg directly with additional information.

Comment: I think @Gyan should post an answer.